# Keep getting a getElementById variable syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, getelementbyid

This code keeps giving me an error about getElementById on line 5, any help?
It says it is not defined.

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('input').onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event; 

    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == '13')
        var commandInput=getElementById("input").value; //this is the line that keeps giving me errors

    testforCommand();   
    return false;  
}
}
```

HTML

```
<body onLoad="typeWriter()">
<p id="output"></p>
</br>
<p> ♮-  </p><input id="input" type="text" maxlength="50" spellcheck="false">
</body>
```

Comment: Please share your relevant HTML as well, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you're looking for `document.getElementById`, rather than just `getElementById`.

Comment: That needs to be `document.getElementById()`, you forgot the `document`. Also: add braces to your `if` blocks. Your code will not perform the way you expect it to.

Comment: You also appear to have an extra closing brace at the end of your JS code, ie `}`. Also, it's `<br/>`, **not** `</br>`

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is declared on `document`, not `window` or global.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be

```
var commandInput=document.getElementById("input").value;
```

Unless you have another function called `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to search for the element which is processing an event. Handlers added with either `addEventListener`, or by setting an `onEventName` property, are called with their `this` value set to the element to which the event listener has been added. Note this need not be the element on which the event was fired if the event has been captured or bubbles up. So all you need in this case is

```
var commandInput = this.value;
```

As already mentioned, the technical reason for the error is that `getElementById` is a method of `document` not `window`.